# Zxing Xamarin: Why not all qr code detected

Tags: xamarin, qr-code, zxing

From the image below, i have 7 qr codes and looks very clear to me. The zxing seems to fail to detect all of them. Only some have detected.

The paper was taken on a flat surface.

I use skiaBitmap to hold the bitmap data and use   https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/blob/master/Source/Bindings/ZXing.SkiaSharp/SKBitmapLuminanceSource.cs

SKBitmapLumianceSource to generate a LumianceSource for HybridBinarizer in Zxing.

Is there a reason that the why zxing cannot detect some of the qr codes? I have even put a hint: TRY_HARDER

[image]

Comment: You want it to detect all of them at once?

Comment: They do not look very "clear" to me, but I do not have the original bitmap source, just a 1kx2k JPG that you posted. I "assume" you are not using a JPG as your source as the lossy compression will cause problems unless your QR codes are **much** larger in the field of view of the camera. If that is an A4 sized piece of paper and your QR codes are that actual size (relative to the A4 size), you will need very good camera to try to capture/scan the entire sheet at once (specialized barcode scanners have much better resolution for tasks like this).